# переписать jQuery решение на чистый JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такое решение на jQuery:

```
jQuery('.buy_button').click(function(){  
    var autoname = jQuery(this).closest('.product-container', ['div']).find('.name-product a').text();     
    jQuery('input.prod_name').val(autoname);         
});
```

используется для автозаполнения поля во всплывающей форме в карточке товара. Как его переписать на чистом JS ?

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, как-то так:

```js
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("buy_button")[0];

button.onclick = function () {
  let container = this.closest('div.product-container');
  let autoname = container.querySelector('.name-product a').innerText;
  container.querySelector('input.prod_name').value = autoname;
};
```

```html
<div class="product-container">
  <button class="buy_button">Click 4 copy!</button>
  <div class="name-product">
    <a>I am LINK</a>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="prod_name">
</div>
```

Если input лежит вне блока `.product-container` то эту строку:

`container.querySelector('input.prod_name').value = autoname;`

меняем на эту:

`document.querySelector('input.prod_name').value = autoname;`

Comment: не работает в ie11, но думаю всем пофиг на него